# Suction of water from a container

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am trying to simulate a suction effect where water is sucked out of an container, flows through a pipe, and comes out the other end. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: hello, it's a bit vague, maybe show us a storyboard? it would help to find the solutions

Comment: @moonboots I have added an image. Is it clearer now

Comment: That's not a storyboard. The image is sort of improvement, but the question is still very vague, the way I see it. It's unclear what the goal is and how it is supposed to look. I would recommend at least describing the context, what and why you are trying to do, maybe add some images illustrating the visuals you are trying to achieve. An actual storyboard would probably get you detailed answers instantly.

Comment: you could create an outflow at the left end of the tube, create an inflow at the tip at the right, and fake a water flow in the tube if it is supposed to be transparent (or a water flow that has a negative gravity)? do you need to create a kind of vacuum hole where the water is sucked?

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys I am trying to visualize water being drawn out of the rectangular enclosure shown above and the water flowing throw the pipe and eventually coming out at the right end of the pipe.

Comment: The challenge is, how do I get the effect of water already filled in the enclsoure and then creating an effect that shows it being sucked into the pipe.

Comment: Well, usually there is no need for any fluid simulation for visualising level of a fluid lowering in a container as it's just a flat surface moving down.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys how exactly do I achieve that flat surface moving down?

Comment: It's not clear to me what the end result should look like. At the moment there is infinite amount of ways to interpret goal. That's why personally I hesitate to provide any answer. I think there are other BSE users in the same position. You would have greater chance of getting good answers if you defined the question better and provided some sketches, storyboard, sample images and all the context. Like what is this for?  What is the scale of the objects, what are they made of, how are they made, what is pumping the water, what is holding the pipe, why and so on.

Comment: My bad, I have not been able to come up with a descriptive storyboard. However in attempt to re-explain. A design project has been done, which included pipe routing and pump sizing. The purpose for this is to visualize the project. The end result include a visualization of water reducing from the enclosure and simultaneously flowing through the pipe and out at the open end of the pipe. A pump is meant to pump out the water.

Is this clearer? @MartynasŽiemys